# How to make this r2dbc url?

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mssql

Properties:

```
Name: app_port_poc
hostname: greshamdevdb01.global.trafigura.com
port: 1521
service name: greshamdev01.global.trafigura.com
```

My application in running in dev profile.

application-dev.yml:

```
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:h2:mem:///ui;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=LEGACY
    username: UI
    password:
```

But failing in prod profile because of some r2dbc connection url issue.
I am using Oracle DB for prod and in-memory H2 DB for dev profile. How can I make a correct r2dbc url?

Comment: How is it failing in prod - do you get an error?

Comment: Do you have a UAT environment? You should have a real-world database configuration (Oracle) before you get to prod, otherwise you'll be testing against the wrong database.